# Pushing session data to a PHP file included via '<script>'

Tags: php, session

I have a small problem that I can't find an exact solution to.

I have a file called push.php that grabs required information from a database, stores the data via SESSIONS and then does a header redirect to listing.php.

Of course as you would expect, listing.php is able to use the session data and display the info.

There is an external php file called in using `<script type="text/javascript" src="map.api.php"></script>` that uses both JS and PHP to generate a map. In the `map.api.php` file it is not letting me echo the session data (and yes, I have started the file with `session_start();`)

How can I post the session data to `map.api.php` without having to reload the page?

Comment: You mean you can't access the specific session data you need or *any* session data?

Comment: None of the session data that I am using in the `listing.php` is accessible in the `map.api.php`... so yeah all of it. I am thinking this has something to do with the fact I am not using `include('map.api.php')` but that is unfortunately not an option.

Comment: Any file participating in the session state would have access to the session data.  Is something else removing those session values before `map.api.php` accesses them?  Is `map.api.php` running in a different server/application context?  The fact that it's referenced from a `script` tag makes *no* difference.

Comment: You meant that `map.api.php` is an external API which doesn't belong to your code and you'd like to POST the session data to it? If so, you can create a new PHP script in your project and POST the data to `map.api.php` by `php-curl`, so that you can use `<script src="redirect_map.api.php"></script>` instead.

Comment: Maybe I should have included more information in the original post. `map.api.php` is using both PHP and JavaScript, so at the top of the file is the following: `header("Content-type: application/javascript");
session_start();`

Comment: @RyanButterworth: There must be something else wrong, outside of what's being described.  Session state is accessible to any page in the application being accessed by the user.

Comment: Nothing is changing the session data values before it calls in the `map.api.php`.... this is weird

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use

```
include map.api.php;
```

instead of

```
<script src="map.api.php"></script>
```

Comment: As David has stated, it makes no difference Jairaj.